# Deploying an MVC app to new server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I just published my MVC application and copied all the files to a new Windows Server 2012. IIS is set up and I placed my files in a folder that IIS points to. However I'm getting this error when I launch the app:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does this mean that MVC was not installed on the server? Should MVC be a separate installation? I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Is Mvc installed in that machine ? If not, did you include MVC dll's as deployable dependency ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc' or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255118/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-mvc-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: You could try to reinstall the package: Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -reinstall

Comment: I installed MVC3 but I get the same error. Actually it's now saying a different version : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.